# Subplots not being printed out

Tags: matplotlib, graph, scatter-plot, subplot

I'm trying to create 2 subplots using a dataframe. Example of  data frame:

[Dataframe I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv5d5.png)

'''

I have created new data frames because I want 4 subplots based on the 4 years available.

```html
year2000=imported_dataframe[imported_dataframe['Year'] ==2000]
year2005=imported_dataframe[imported_dataframe['Year'] ==2005]
year2010=imported_dataframe[imported_dataframe['Year'] ==2010]
year2015=imported_dataframe[imported_dataframe['Year'] ==2015]

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)


colors = {'Africa':u'orchid', 'Americas':u'darkcyan', 'Asia':'blue', 'Europe': 'yellow', 'Oceania':'purple'}
colors = imported_dataframe.Region.map(colors)
colors2000=year2000.Region.map(colors)
x, y = imported_dataframe['Proportion of births attended by skilled health personnel (%)'],imported_dataframe['Maternal mortality ratio'] 

x1,y1=year2000['Proportion of births attended by skilled health personnel (%)'],year2000['Maternal mortality ratio'] 






ax1.scatter( x,y, c=colors)
ax2.scatter( x1,y1, c=colors2000)
```

I have then tried to use plt subplots to create the two graphs I wanted. Note that one graph (i.e. ax1) is a scatterplot that isn't segregated by year but ax2 is segregated by year 2000.

I keep getting this error:
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7fa7ca88bbb0>
<**array_function** internals>:5: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
/Users/sandithilewanda/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:102: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

**I have tried fixing this by making sure that both graphs were segregated versions but nothing is working**. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are overriding `colors`. Initially you set it as mapping for each Region, then you override it and map it for all colors for all years. I have changed the map to be written into `colormap`. Update the 3 lines like this and it should resolve your issue.
Note: My data may not match yours as you didnt provide any. Used some random data for testing.

```
colormap = {'Africa':u'orchid', 'Americas':u'darkcyan', 'Asia':'blue', 'Europe': 'yellow', 'Oceania':'purple'}
colors = imported_dataframe.Region.map(colormap)
colors2000=year2000.Region.map(colormap)
```

**Plot**

[image]